# Tricks for fitting data in nlme?

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nlme

When I fit data in nlme, I never succeed on the first try, and after `nlme(fit.model)` I am accustomed to seeing things such as:

```
Error in nlme.formula(model = mass ~ SSbgf(day, w.max, t.e, t.m), random = list( :
  step halving factor reduced below minimum in PNLS step

Error in MEestimate(nlmeSt, grpShrunk) : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

So I go back and

1)Change the units of the x-axis (e.g. from years to days, or days to growing degree days).

2)Make a x=0, y=0 measurement in my dataset

3)Add a `random=pdDiag()`

4)Mess with what is random and what is fixed

5)Chop up my dataset and try to fit different parts at different times

6)Achieve a very simple fit, then use `update` to make the model proper

Eventually something seems to work.  Does anyone else have something to add to this list?  What helps you get nlme to work with your data?

I realize this question will probably be closed, but if there are any suggestions on how to reword it to be acceptable to SO, I would appreciate the input.

Here is an example where I have tried some of these things, but have not had success so far:

The data:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/4inldx7617fip01/proots.csv . This is already just a portion of the whole set.

The code:

```
roots<-read.table("proots.csv", header = TRUE)

#roots$day[roots$year == 2007] <- 0 #when I use a dataset with time=0, mass=0
roots$day[roots$year == 2008] <- 153
roots$day[roots$year == 2009] <- 518
roots$day[roots$year == 2010] <- 883
roots$day[roots$year == 2011] <- 1248
roots$day[roots$year == 2012] <- 1613
roots$day[roots$year == 2013] <- 1978

#or bigger time steps
roots$time[roots$year == 2008] <- 1
roots$time[roots$year == 2009] <- 2
roots$time[roots$year == 2010] <- 3
roots$time[roots$year == 2011] <- 4
roots$time[roots$year == 2012] <- 5
roots$time[roots$year == 2013] <- 6

roots$EU<- with(roots, factor(plot):factor(depth)) #EU is "experimental unit"
rootsG<-groupedData(mass ~ day | EU, data=roots)

#I will post the SSbgf function below -- run it first
fit.beta <- nlsList(mass ~ SSbgf(day, w.max, t.e, t.m), data = rootsG) 

fit.nlme.bgf<-nlme(fit.beta)
fit.nlme.bgf<-nlme(fit.beta, random=list(w.max + t.e + t.m ~1))
fit.nlme.bgf<-nlme(fit.beta, random=list(w.max ~ 1))
fit.nlme.bgf<-nlme(fit.beta, random=pdDiag(w.max ~1))

fit.nlme.bgf<-nlme(fit.beta, random=pdDiag(w.max + t.e + t.m ~1))
fit.nlme.bgf<-nlme(fit.beta, random=list(t.m ~1)) 
fit.nlme.bgf<-nlme(fit.beta, random=list(t.e ~1))

fit.nlme.bgf<-nlme(fit.beta, random=pdSymm(w.max ~1))
fit.nlme.bgf<-nlme(fit.beta, random=pdDiag(w.max ~1))
```

And here is the function (SSbgf) for the curve:

```
bgfInit <- function(mCall, LHS, data){

  xy <- sortedXyData(mCall[["time"]], LHS, data)
  if(nrow(xy) < 4){
    stop("Too few distinct input values to fit a bgf")
  }
  w.max <- max(xy[,"y"])
  t.e <- NLSstClosestX(xy, w.max)
  t.m <- NLSstClosestX(xy, w.max/2)
  value <- c(w.max, t.e, t.m)
  names(value) <- mCall[c("w.max","t.e","t.m")]
  value

}


bgf <- function(time, w.max, t.e, t.m){

  .expr1 <- t.e / (t.e - t.m)
  .expr2 <- (time/t.e)^.expr1
  .expr3 <- (1 + (t.e - time)/(t.e - t.m))
  .value <- w.max * .expr3 * .expr2

  ## Derivative with respect to t.e
  .exp1 <- ((time/t.e)^(t.e/(t.e - t.m))) * ((t.e-time)/(t.e-t.m) + 1)
  .exp2 <- (log(time/t.e)*((1/(t.e-t.m) - (t.e/(t.e-t.m)^2) - (1/(t.e - t.m)))))*w.max
  .exp3 <- (time/t.e)^(t.e/(t.e-t.m))
  .exp4 <- w.max * ((1/(t.e-t.m)) - ((t.e - time)/(t.e-t.m)^2))
  .exp5 <- .exp1 * .exp2 + .exp3 * .exp4 

  ## Derivative with respect to t.m
  .ex1 <- t.e * (time/t.e)^((t.e/(t.e - t.m))) * log(time/t.e) * ((t.e - time)/(t.e -     
 t.m) + 1) * w.max
  .ex2 <- (t.e - time) * w.max * (time/t.e)^(t.e/(t.e-t.m))
  .ex3 <- (t.e - t.m)^2
  .ex4 <- .ex1 / .ex3 + .ex2 / .ex3

  .actualArgs <- as.list(match.call()[c("w.max", "t.e", "t.m")])

##  Gradient
  if (all(unlist(lapply(.actualArgs, is.name)))) {
    .grad <- array(0, c(length(.value), 3L), list(NULL, c("w.max", 
                                                      "t.e", "t.m")))
    .grad[, "w.max"] <- .expr3 * .expr2
    .grad[, "t.e"] <- .exp5
    .grad[, "t.m"] <- .ex4 
    dimnames(.grad) <- list(NULL, .actualArgs)
    attr(.value, "gradient") <- .grad
  }
    .value
}

SSbgf <- selfStart(bgf, initial = bgfInit, c("w.max", "t.e", "t.m"))
```

Comment: This is potentially a very interesting question. Why don't you give us a reproducible example?

Comment: Let me know if that is not reproducible, @BenBolker.  Or if you would like one that was successful (it has happened).

Answer (score 6):

Another trick is to increase the pnls tolerance.

The required code would be:

```
control = nlmeControl(pnlsTol = x, msVerbose = TRUE)
```

The starting value for pnls tolerance is 0.001, so I like to start with 0.01 or 0.02.  Just replace x with your number and you should be set.