# Error message in nlme example present in R but not in S

Tags: r, nlme

I am working through *Mixed Effects Models in S and S-Plus* in R but some of the code does not produce the results in-text. In Chapter 6 one of the examples fails to converge with the code supplied.

The example is a non-linear mixed effects model performed on the `Phenobarb` dataset supplied with the `nlme` package.

```
library(nlme)

fm1Pheno.nlme <- nlme(model = conc ~ phenoModel(Subject, time, dose, lCl, lV),
                      data = Phenobarb,
                      fixed = lCl + lV ~ 1,
                      random = pdDiag(lCl + lV ~ 1),
                      start = c(-5,0),
                      na.action = na.pass, 
                      naPattern = ~ !is.na(conc))

fm1Pheno.nlme
```

This first model runs fine, but the second model, based on the first

```
fm2Pheno.nlme <- update( fm1Pheno.nlme,
                         fixed = list(lCl ~ Wt, lV ~ Wt + ApgarInd),
                         start = c(-5.0935, 0, 0.34259, 0, 0),
                         control = list(pnlsTol = 1e-6) )
```

..returns the error

```
Error in nlme.formula(model = conc ~ phenoModel(Subject, time, dose, lCl,  : 
  maximum number of iterations (maxIter = 50) reached without convergence
```

This second model apparently work in S but not in R. Can anyone suggest a solution? Is the error due to some difference between S and R?

Comment: I've tried a few things (using `opt="nlm"` and/or `maxIter=2000` in `control()`, changing `pnlsTol` back to the default 1e-3), but no luck so far.

Comment: Thanks for trying @Ben Bolker. Not the end of the world. Almost everything else in the book translates just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may deal with this by adjusting the `pnlsTol` parameter:

```
fm2Pheno.nlme <- update(fm1Pheno.nlme,
                        fixed = list(lCl ~ Wt, lV ~ Wt + ApgarInd),
                        start = c(-5.0935, 0, 0.34259, 0, 0),
                        control = list(pnlsTol = 0.019))
```

To see why it makes sense, try adding `msVerbose = TRUE` to `control` and see how the values keep jumping around if the tolerance parameter is low. Increasing `pnlsTol` is a pretty common way to deal with such convergence issues, see, e.g.,

- [Tricks for fitting data in nlme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921047/tricks-for-fitting-data-in-nlme)
- [Gastric Emptying Analysis with R: Miscellaneous](https://menne-biomed.de/gastempt/gastemptmisc.html)
- [Correlation structure of nested nonlinear mixed model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258378/correlation-structure-of-nested-nonlinear-mixed-model)
- [[R] nlme and pnlsTol](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-December/062604.html)
- [[R-sig-ME] nlme: "Singularity in backsolve" error in ODE-defined,  but not in closed-form model](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2007q2/000195.html)

Comment: Thank you @Julius Vainora. Seems like `pnlsTol` is a good way to get recalcitrant models to converge.